# Iterate through new data type of nested lists in haskell

Tags: haskell, types, nested, nested-lists

I am new at making new types in Haskell. This is my type that I created:

```
data Tag = Table | Td | Tr deriving(Show)
data Table = Item Tag [Table] | Text String
```

The Tag data type also has a show function where it prints the values to a string. I know this type works recursively because Table uses [Table] in the first value. I want to be able to make a list of all of the Tag elements and the innermost element, which will be Text or an empty list.

For example:

```hs
>example = Item Table [Item Td [Item Tr [Text "hello"]]]
>tableList example
["Table","Td","Tr","hello"]
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```hs
tableList :: Table -> [String]
tableList (Item tag _) = [x | x <- show tag]
```

But this only shows `"table"`. I'm not sure how to access all of the inner `Tag` values.

Comment: Where's the definition of the type `Tag`?

Comment: Also, do you mean `example = Item table [Item t [Item r [Text "hello"]]]`?

Comment: @JosephSible I edited the post. `data Tag = table | t | r`. Tag has a show function where it just prints the value in a string. I also changed the example. Thank you for catching that!

Comment: That's not a valid definition of Tag. Data constructors aren't allowed to start with lowercase letters.

Comment: @JosephSible my mistake, didn't compile it previously.

Comment: And now your example doesn't match the type.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of finishing fixing the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your recursive type needs a recursive function to walk it:

```
tableList :: Table -> [String]
tableList (Item tag xs) = show tag:concatMap tableList xs
tableList (Text t) = [t]
```